# change content based on timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

The click functions I made change the content. But, whenever I use `setinterval` or `settimeout`, the functions run 1 time and then run again immediately without using the delay.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('.seashellcontainertwo').hide();

  var settimer = 1;

  $('.seashellcontainer').click(function() {
    settimer = 0;
    $('.seashellcontainer').hide();
    $('.seashellcontainertwo').show();
  });

  $('.seashellcontainertwo').click(function() {
    settimer = 0;
    $('.seashellcontainertwo').hide();
    $('.seashellcontainer').show();
  });


  if (settimer == 1) {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('.seashellcontainertwo').hide();
      $('.seashellcontainer').show();
    }, 3000);
    setInterval(function() {
      $('.seashellcontainertwo').show();
      $('.seashellcontainer').hide();
    }, 3000);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seashellcontainer">seashellcontainer</div>
<div class="seashellcontainertwo">seashellcontainertwo</div>
```

Comment: It looks like your two timers will run nearly simultaneously. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose,this is what you were trying to achieve in `intervals`, Not sure about `click` events though. Further clarification will help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var seaShellContainerTwo = $('.seashellcontainertwo');
  var seaShellContainer = $('.seashellcontainer');
  seaShellContainerTwo.hide();
  var settimer = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    if (settimer === 1) {
      seaShellContainerTwo.hide();
      seaShellContainer.show();
      settimer = 0;
    } else {
      seaShellContainerTwo.show();
      seaShellContainer.hide();
      settimer = 1;
    }
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seashellcontainer">seashellcontainer</div>
<div class="seashellcontainertwo">seashellcontainertwo</div>
```

Comment: Well basically it was 2 different functions.

1 is that when you click on the item it switches.
2 is that after x seconds, it scrolls to the next one and goes back forth between the 2 automatically.

also that if condition 2 fires if you dont click on items. if you do conditiion1 only fires.